# core data cascade does not delete relationship

Tags: core-data

I have a bill entity that has among others a to-many relationship with billingdetails entities.
[see the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p66G8.png)

The delete rule on Bill.billingdetails is Cascade and billingdetails is not optional.
The delete rule on BillingDetails.bill is Nullify and bill is not optional either.

Now, when I delete a bill it gets deleted, however the associated billingdetails are not deleted. They're not even touched. I put a log message into BillingDetails prepareForDeletion method, and the method is not called. 
The only method that I wrote for BillingDetails is this:

```
@implementation BillingDetails

// Custom logic goes here.
- (void)copyFromSession:(Session *)session {
    self.session_date = session.date;
    self.session_duration = session.duration;
    self.session_factor = session.factor;
    self.session_goaecode = session.treatment.goaecode;
    self.session_unitprice = session.treatment.price;
    if ([self.bill.patient.language isEqualToString:@"English"]) {
        self.session_treatment = session.treatment.descriptionEnglish;
    }
    if ([self.bill.patient.language isEqualToString:@"German"]) {
        self.session_treatment = session.treatment.descriptionGerman;
    }
}

@end
```

This is the test I'm using and it consistently fails on the second assertion (about `BillingDetails`):
(`sut` in this context is the `Bill` under test)

```
- (void)testBillDeleteDeletesAllBillingdetails {
    NSString *markMeString = @"Find me if you can";
    NSDate   *markMeDate   = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        for (BillingDetails *billingdetails in sut.billingdetails) {
            billingdetails.session_treatment = markMeString;
        }
        sut.date = markMeDate;
        [sut MR_deleteEntity];
    }];
    XCTAssertNil([Bill MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"date" withValue:markMeDate]);
    XCTAssertEqual([BillingDetails MR_findByAttribute:@"session_treatment" withValue:markMeString].count, 0);

}
```

I did use this to work around the problem, and it works.

```
@implementation Bill

// Custom logic goes here.

… omitted to shorten …

- (void)prepareForDeletion {
    for (BillingDetails *bd in self.billingdetails) {
        [bd MR_deleteEntity];
    }
}

@end
```

But I don't think that this is really the way to go.

I don't know where to look for the problem anymore. I don't see any dependencies that might interfere here.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe Magical Record is not reliable. In plain vanilla Core Data what you describe always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to emulate the delete rules with my own code, I realized what was causing the failure of cascading.

My `bill` also has a `patient` relationship. When that was set, the `billingdetails` were populated with unbilled `sessions` from the `patient`. Before actually adding `billingdetails` the `billingdetails` property was reset to nil.

And that caused a chain reaction. 
Deleting `bill`, first nullified the `patient` relationship. With setting the `patient` property to nil, in turn the `billingdetails` were nullified and could not be found by the cascading mechanism anymore.
But of course I had left the billing details floating.
It was my mistake. Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly you are not **saving** the changes. If you delete a `Bill` on the main context it will not show up in your UI any more, but nothing is actually deleted until you save.

Comment: Thanks Mundi. I am testing that with assertions. I'll update my question to show my test. Everything should get saved.